# Why do attributes type change from float to number?

Tags: types, attributes, fiware, fiware-orion

I've noticed that when I register entities with some 'float' attributes in Orion, after some updates the type is changed to 'number' instead of 'float'.

For example:

```
{ "id":"my_entity", 
  "type":"entity_type",
  "attr1":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":"0.54",
      "metadata":{}},
  "attr2":{
      "type":"Number",
      "value":44.3,
      "metadata":{}}}]
```

In this case, when my_entity was registered, both types of attributes were 'float'. When some update was made in the value of the attr2, its type was changed to 'Number'. Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to default typing, as described in the "Partial Representations" section in the [NGSIv2 spec](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable):

> Attribute/metadata `type` may be omitted in requests. When omitted in attribute/metadata creation or in update operations, a default is used for the type depending on the value:
>
> - If value is a string, then type `Text` is used
> - If value is a number, then type `Number` is used.
> - If value is a boolean, then type `Boolean` is used.
> - If value is an object or array, then `StructuredValue` is used.
> - If value is null, then `None` is used.

Thus, probably you are updating your attribute using the following (o a similar) API operation:

```
PUT /v2/entities/my_entity/attrs/attr2

{
  "value": 44.3
}
```

and `type` omission in that payload is triggering the default typing feature.

Basically, there are two solutions to this:

1. Use `type` in your attribute update operation:

   ```
   PUT /v2/entities/my_entity/attrs/attr2

   {
     "type": "float",
     "value": 44.3
   }
   ```
2. Use the attribute value update operation (which doesn't touch type or metadata):

   ```
   PUT /v2/entities/my_entity/attrs/attr2/value

   44.3
   ```

Comment: I've chosen the first option, which is the use of "type" in the request. It is better for me because I am updating more than one attribute at a time (request). I updated the answer because it was lacking the "type" in the code. =)
Thanks.

Comment: You are right... sorry! I have eddited your suggestion, adding `"` (i.e. `"float"`).